# BibLaTeX alphabetic style sorting strange

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have got a problem with the sorting order in my bibliography.

My setup:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
```

According to BibLaTeX documentation default sorting order should be `anyt`. This is working fine but when I have got an organization as author (with white space) like in the BibTex entry below the sorting is very strange.

```
@report{CiscoSystems.2015,
 author = {{Cisco Systems}},
 date = {2015},
 title = {Cisco Global Cloud Index: Forecast and Methodology 2014-2019},
 url = {http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/service-provider/global-cloud-index-gci/Cloud_Index_White_Paper.pdf},
 urldate = {2016-03-14},
 institution = {{Cisco Systems}},
 year = {2015},
 type = {White Paper}
}
```

As you can see in the attached screenshot the alphalabel is generated properly but the sorting is not correct. Manually changing the sort order by using e.g. `sorting=none` or using `editor` instead of `author` does not change anything. If I remove the white space from `Cisco Systems` sorting is correct.

[image: Bibliography]

It seems like authors containing white spaces are not sorted correctly altough sorting order should be by alphalabel (which is also correct and makes it even stranger). I used double curly brackets as described in the package documentation. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\cite{Marian.2012}
\cite{CiscoSystems.2015}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And this is the BibTex file I am using:

```
@article{Marian.2012,
 author = {Marian, Matei},
 year = {2012},
 title = {iPaaS: Different Ways of Thinking},
 pages = {1093--1098},
 volume = {3},
 issn = {22125671},
 journal = {Procedia Economics and Finance},
 doi = {10.1016/S2212-5671(12)00279-1}
}

@report{CiscoSystems.2015,
 author = {{Cisco Systems}},
 date = {2015},
 title = {Cisco Global Cloud Index: Forecast and Methodology 2014-2019},
 url = {http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/service-provider/global-cloud-index-gci/Cloud_Index_White_Paper.pdf},
 urldate = {2016-03-14},
 institution = {{Cisco Systems}},
 year = {2015},
 type = {White Paper}
}
```

Comment: Can you prepare a full MWE that we can copy, paste and run on our machines to reproduce the error? You could also try and run Biber as a back-end and not BibTeX ([see here for help for you editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)).

Comment: @moewe I edited my question and added download link for my MWE.

Comment: OK, BibTeX thinks it needs to sort `{Cisco Systems}` under `{C}` and not `C`. The easiest solution is to switch to Biber.

Comment: Please note that it is better to include the MWE in the question directly as plain text. People are wary of clicking links and downloading stuff from  sites they don't know, and rightly so.

Comment: @moewe You are right. I switched to Biber and now it gets sorted correctly. Thanks a lot. Please answer my question that I can give you the reputation you deserve :) PS: I also added my MWE directly to improve my question.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372093/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (correctly placed) braces throw BibTeX off when sorting and let it think the names should be sorted under `{C}` and not `C`.

If there is no substantial reason not to use Biber, I suggest you ditch BibTeX and switch over to Biber. Biber ignores the braces when sorting and sorts the entry correctly under `C`.

---

Alternatively, with BibTeX you can specify the `label` manually without the braces

```
@report{CiscoSystems.2015,
 author = {{Cisco Systems}},
 label  = {Cis},
 date = {2015},
 title = {Cisco Global Cloud Index: Forecast and Methodology 2014-2019},
 url = {http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/service-provider/global-cloud-index-gci/Cloud_Index_White_Paper.pdf},
 urldate = {2016-03-14},
 type = {White Paper}
}
```